# Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

On the site https://gearbottle.com/ I am having an issue where the map will load my geolocation (enable geolocation to see) and then load all results (the entire world) - I need this to stay at the geolocation and not jump to the entire map.

***After checking out the console I see "Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired //developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required***" and then a dropdown of ***Object*** etc....After digging a bit i came across the following scripts that still have the sensors in place:

```js
if(ddp('google_places_api')) { if(ddp('google_places_api') != '') { wp_register_script('google_maps_api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='.ddp('google_places_api').'&sensor=false&libraries=places'); } }
  else { wp_register_script('google_maps_api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?'); }
  
 }
```

```js
 $google_places_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?key='.ddp('google_places_api').'&sensor=false&input='.$fields[$field->post_name].'&types=(regions)';
```

```js
$reference_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?key='.ddp('google_places_api').'&sensor=false&reference='.$place_reference;
```

....but I am clueless on what to replace the "Sensor" part in each script to or if this even matters - I really just need the map to stop jumping and that's really it.

**This is an older version of a theme that has been reconstructed (purchased by choice)- there is no longer support from original devs, so I am attempting to fix things on my own.**

Comment: replace `&sensor=false` with nothing, nada. zip, zero length string :p

Comment: Lol - ok, let me give that a shot.

Comment: that will get rid of the warning - not sure about your problem

Answer (score 15):

As per the documentation on [Google Map Error Codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required) for  SensorNotRequired

> The sensor parameter is no longer required for the Google Maps
>   JavaScript API. It won't prevent the Google Maps JavaScript API from
>   working correctly, but we recommend that you remove the sensor
>   parameter from the script element.

It is a warning and you can safely remove `&sensor=false` from the urls